# Can not select the latest ID from store, withLatestFrom returns previous ID and not last, why?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, typescript-typings

I am trying to create a master/detail page and I need the master id to retrieve the related records of the detail list.

I have a selector

```typescript
export const selectRecords= (state: CoreState) => state.records;

export const getId = createSelector(selectRecords,
    (state: myState) => state && state.selectedRecords && state.selectedRecords.id
);
```

and in my effect I am trying to get the latest id from the store with something like:

```typescript
@Effect()
    getSomething$ = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType<GetMyRecords>(MyType.GET_RECORDS),
        withLatestFrom(this.store.select(getId)),
        switchMap(([action, id]) => {
            this.log.debug('Get ID', id);
            ... calling my service here
        })
    );
```

but even while I am using `withLatestFrom`, what I am getting is the previous ID and not the latest.

When I am checking the console from Redux, the selectedRecords.id in the state is the correct one (the latest), the one I would like to retrieve.

I know it's a longshot, but does anyone have a tip or advice what I could try to get the correct last id from the store?

Comment: Can you replace `withLatestFrom(this.store.select(getId))` with `switchMap((action) => this.store.select(getId).pipe(map(id => ([action, id])), take(1)))` and see if that helps,

Comment: @WillTaylor same result. First time I am getting error, then when I go back to my list and from my list to details where I have to load the grid based on the ID of the master, It's using the previous visited details id. It's like it's always one step behind, even though in REDUX I see the correct ID.

Comment: Maybe it helps but I just tried combineLatest instead of withLatestFrom and it worked. But I am getting a warning 'combineLatest' is deprecated.

Comment: I tried to replace it and load it from combineLatest from 'rxjs' instead of 'rxjs/operators' but like this it needs a second argument and what I am doing is not really combining two selects. I don't know with the operator worked though...

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve the problem by adding a debounceTime(0) before the withLatestFrom:

The update working code is:

```
@Effect()
    getSomething$ = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType<GetMyRecords>(MyType.GET_RECORDS),
        debounceTime(0),
        withLatestFrom(this.store.select(getId)),
        switchMap(([action, id]) => {
            this.log.debug('Get ID', id);
            ... calling my service here
        })
    );
```

and I am adding a link that describes the excact issue I had:
https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/issues/1121

> In other words .withLatestFrom(item.asObservable()) can't provide
> actual latest next event's non nil value, but provide the previous
> one's nil value!